# Can't have only digits in URL subpart sequence

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, digits

I want to change regex so it matches if class group doesn't have only digits between two slashes:

```
$regex = "~^upload/(?<class>[/a-z0-9_\.]+)/(?<id_table>\d+)$~";

preg_match($regex, "upload/.bes/.ur/13"); // returns true
preg_match($regex, "upload/.tables/fewf/.u23ser/15"); // returns true
preg_match($regex, "upload/.t/les2/.uer/11"); // returns true
preg_match($regex, "upload/1.tales/.user2/01"); // returns true

preg_match($regex, "upload/23/21"); // returns false
preg_match($regex, "upload/.tables/00/31"); // returns false
preg_match($regex, "upload/6/.uer/q/51"); // returns false
```

Comment: You're missing the delimiters. This should result in error messages.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to write them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$regex = "~^upload/(?<class>(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+(?:/(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+)*)/(?<id_table>\d+)$~";
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/czCbn8/3).

The `class` named group pattern matches

- `(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+`  - one or more lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `_` or `.`, but not if all these chars are digits
- `(?:/(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `_` or `.`, but not if all these chars are digits

Comment: [^/] doesn't help me. I need in <class> group only these [/a-z0-9_\.] chars.

Comment: @Arșavin Ok, see the edit. Note you do not need to escape a dot inside a character class, it matches a dot there. That is not the point, the point is the negative lookahead.

Comment: @Arșavin You misplaced the lookahead, here is the [correct demo](https://regex101.com/r/czCbn8/2).

Comment: Yeah. But <id_external> isn't matched anyway. Please, analize it.

Comment: @Arșavin Try replacing your class pattern with `(?<class>(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+(?:/(?!\d+/)[a-z0-9_.]+)*)`. See https://regex101.com/r/czCbn8/3

Comment: Actually. I found the answer: (?<class>(\D[a-z0-9_.]+/)+)

Comment: @Arșavin But that allows consecutive `/`s and requires at least 2 chars in a subpart. That is a bad idea.

Comment: So, how to fix it?

Comment: @Arșavin See my updated answer. And the above [link](https://regex101.com/r/czCbn8/3) to the overall pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your named capture starting with the digit class with a possessive quantifier:

```
(?<class>\d*+[a-z0-9_.]+(?>/\d*+[a-z0-9_.]+)*)
```

Since the quantifier is possessive, you are sure that the first character matched by `[a-z0-9_.]+` is not a digit.

Comment: @Arșavin: it isn't a problem, it works too. https://regex101.com/r/uoyXdq/1

Comment: Indeed. I made tests. Is better because i don't match also the last slash, which I don't need of. You are cool.

Comment: But Wiktor Stribiżew answered first and I already accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, we could simplify that with this expression:

```
(\/[0-9]+\/)|([0-9]+$)
```

If the left capturing group return TRUE, then it is false, otherwise it would be TRUE.

---

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cVL93v/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(\/[0-9]+\/)|([0-9]+$)/m';
$str = 'upload/.bes/.ur/13
upload/.tables/.u23ser/15
upload/.tles2/.uer/11
upload/1.tales/.user2/01

upload/23/21
upload/.tables/00/31
upload/6/.uer/51';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (sizeof($match) == 2) {
        echo "false \n";
    } elseif (sizeof($match) == 3) {
        echo "true \n";
    } else {
        "Something is not right!  \n";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
true 
true 
true 
true 
false 
true 
false 
true 
false 
true
```

---

Once filtering out the undesired strings is done, we can simply capture those classes with:

```
^(upload\/.*?)[0-9]+$
```

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/d8KPY4/1/)

Comment: I'm not interested abot <id_table>. Only about <class> without knowing how many slashes it has.

Comment: I need that groups Emma. I need that <id_table>.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway.